# Problema ao inciar solução visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Problema VisualStudio]

eu quero abrir essa solução mas nao consigo, alguem poderia me ajudar a resolver esse erro?

Comment: como assim "Abrir"? você quer executar ela?

Comment: sim, quero executar ela, fazer debuggar

Comment: o problema é exatamente o que está na mensagem *"Não é possível iniciar um tipo de saída de biblioteca de classes diretamente"*. Você não executa diretamente um projeto de classes, tem de ser algo "executável" como um *Console Application*, *Windows Form Application* ou *Web Application* por exemplo, e esse sim "chamar" a biblioteca de classe

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que estou vendo seu projeto é de **testes**, projetos de testes não são *debugados* da "forma tradicional".

Não sei se existem outras opções, mas a que conheço é pelo *Test Explorer*, para abri-lo, pesquise "test explorer" na caixa de pesquisa do visual studio
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, irá abrir uma janela(normalmente na lateral esquerda), Casos os testes não aprecem, recompile o projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebi também que está usando o **NUnit**. Pode ser que seja necessário instalar o *Adapter* dele para que os testes aparecem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

A biblioteca de classes é como se fosse um livro, no seu caso está acontecendo o seguinte: O *Livro* está tentando ler o Humano e não o *Humano* ler o Livro. Entendeu?

O *Humano* seria o .EXE e o *Livro* seria a Biblioteca de Classes

Como vc criou uma solução do tipo Biblioteca de Classes, então nesta solução só vai ter Biblioteca de Classes. Se vc criar projetos .EXE dentro desta solução, vai dar erros porque a solução é como se fosse uma estante cheia de projetos(livros) que foi criada com a finalidade de apenas armazenar livros e nunca ser iniciada.

Para resolver o problema, tente criar uma solução que tenha um ponto de partida como (*windows form*, *wpf*, *console application*, ...), aí sim vc consegue criar várias bibliotecas com um ponto de partida já configurado automaticamente para efetuar a leitura das (biblioteca).

Answer (score 0):

Vai no menu "Projeto"->"Propriedade de 'nome-do-projeto' ". Em tipo de saída troca para "Aplicativo do Console"